# Discrete version of this transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the following transform for $t>0, a_i>0$
$$f(t)=\sum_{i=0}^d a_i \exp(-t a_i)$$

And I need to invert it for a set of target values $b$:

Find $(t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_d)$ such that $f(t_0),f(t_1),\ldots,f(t_d)=(b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_d)$

Is there a way to express either forward or backward operation in terms of some standard transform that's practical to use?

In the continuous world, this [can be turned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242534/inverse-of-integral-transform-fs-int-0-infty-gx-exp-s-gx-mathbbdx/4244315#4244315) into Laplace Transform. However, this involves taking derivatives and inverse functions, so I'm not sure what's the best way to do this in discrete world.

Continuous version is written in terms of Laplace transform as follows:

$$f(t)=\int_0^\infty g(i) \exp(-t g(i))=\mathcal{L}(yg^{-1}(y)'\mathbb{I}_y)$$

where $g^{-1}(y)'$ represents derivative of functional inverse of $g$ and $\mathbb{I}_y$ is 1 for $y$ between 0 and 1 and $0$ otherwise

Comment: Is $a_i$ truly arbitrary or does it follow a known function?

Comment: $a_i$ is a vector of physical measurements, so we don't know the underlying function

Comment: What about expressing $f(t)$ as the [z-transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) of some finite-length discrete-time signal, and then computing the inverse z-transform?

Comment: @mhdadk how do I turn it into z-transform?

Comment: Nevemind, seems to be a dead end.